# How to install ochem for texlive

Tags: texlive

I found this package for latex that gives me the ability to typeset organic structural formulae and reaction schemes for chemistry. I'm having trouble with installing it though.

I read through the installation steps in the manual and it tells me that I need to edit the `install.cfg.UNIX` file which contains:

```
[PATH]
BINDIR=/usr/local/ochem
M4BINDIR=/usr/bin
INCDIR=/usr/local/ochem
DVIPSDIR=/usr/local/tetex/dvips/ochem
STYLEDIR=/usr/local/tetex/tex/latex/ochem
MODULDIR=/usr/local/ochem
DOCDIR=/usr/local/ochem/doc

[SYSTEM]
SYSTEM=UNIX
```

So I edited the file to this:

```
[PATH]
BINDIR=/usr/share/ochem
M4BINDIR=/usr/bin
INCDIR=/usr/share/ochem
DVIPSDIR=/usr/share/texmf-texlive/dvips/ochem
STYLEDIR=/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/ochem
MODULDIR=/usr/share/ochem
DOCDIR=/usr/share/ochem/doc

[SYSTEM]
SYSTEM=UNIX
```

When I try to install the package, it says that it works, but when I try to typeset one of the examples, it tells me that it can't find `ochem.sty`. I then tried navigating to the directories that the install was supposed to make and they didn't exist. So I made the directories manually and tried the install again. I still get the missing `ochem.sty` error.

Did I edit `install.cfg.UNIX` correctly? My latex distribution is texlive 2009 on Ubuntu 10.10.

NOTE: I did try running `sudo texhash` and it still doesn't work.

EDIT:
I did try running the install script as root, but it didn't work. Then I made the directories manually, and that didn't work either.

Here is the link to the package that I downloaded:
http://www.2k-software.de/download/ochem_40d.zip

Comment: Probably a silly question: did you run the install script as root (or via `sudo`)?  That it didn't create the directories makes me wonder about that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.stackexchange! Please add a link to the package (the `ochem` package on ctan doesn't contain a file named `install.cfg.UNIX`)

Comment: Maybe `install.cfg.UNIX` should be renamed to `install.cfg`?

Comment: Would you be willing to try another package? [chemfig](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/chemfig.html) uses Tikz, and is part of TeX Live.

Comment: if you are using TeXLive 2009 or greater, downloaded from TUG (not from your distro's repo) then you can add/install/updated using `tlmgr` -- the package manager for TeXLive.

Comment: @Caramdir - The `.UNIX` is needed for the install script `install.pl` to know that it's installing on a unix machine rather than a windows machine.

Comment: @Mica: this is not relevant here, since `ochem` is not included in TeX Live.

Comment: @user2485: I would use directories under `/usr/local` (like `/usr/local/share/texmf`, which should be the output of `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL`), but I don't think it is related to your problem. What's the output of the installer script (run as root, and after creating all the diretories mentioned in `install.cfg.UNIX`)?

Answer (score 2):

The following shell script install `ochem` from CTAN and the one you linked successfully into my TeXLive 2010 installation under Ubuntu Linux 10.10.

You most likely need to adjust the `TEXLIVE` and the `BIN` variables.

```
#!/bin/bash -x

TEXLIVE=/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist
SCRIPTS=$TEXLIVE/scripts/ochem
DOCS=$TEXLIVE/doc/latex/ochem
SOURCES=$TEXLIVE/source/latex/ochem
PACKAGE=$TEXLIVE/tex/latex/ochem
BIN=/usr/bin

mkdir -p $SCRIPTS
mkdir -p $DOCS
mkdir -p $SOURCES
mkdir -p $PACKAGE
chmod +x *.pl
cp *.pl *.pm $SCRIPTS
cp *.ps manual/* readme.txt $DOCS
cp *.tex *.inc $SOURCES
cp *.sty $PACKAGE

# Install scripts
cd $BIN
# Link makePics:
ln -s $SCRIPTS/makePics.pl makePics

# Generate wrapper for 'chemie.pl'
# Needs to get started with the '$SCRIPTS' folder as include folder
echo '#!/bin/sh' > ./chemie
echo "/usr/bin/env perl -I$SCRIPTS $SCRIPTS/chemie.pl" >> ./chemie
chmod +x ./chemie

# Ensure proper owner and permissions:
chown -R --reference=$TEXLIVE $SCRIPTS $DOCS $SOURCES $PACKAGES
chmod -R --reference=$TEXLIVE $SCRIPTS $DOCS $SOURCES $PACKAGES
chmod +x $SCRIPTS/*.pl

texhash
```